# Mongoid returns inconsistent doc id after multiple upserts of the same document

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm using the mongoid gem in Ruby. Each time I upsert, save or insert the same unique document in a collection, the Ruby instance shows a different id. For example, I have a script like so:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email, type: String
  field :name, type: String
  index({ email: 1}, { unique: true })
  create_indexes
end

u=User.new(email: 'test@testers.edu', name: "Mr. Testy")
u.upsert
puts u.to_json
```

The first time I run it against an empty or non-existent collection, I get this output

```
{"_id":"52097dee5feea8384a000001","email":"test@testers.edu","name":"Mr. Testy"}
```

If I run it again, I get this:

```
{"_id":"52097e805feea8575a000001","email":"test@testers.edu","name":"Mr. Testy"}
```

But the document in MongoDB still shows the first id (52097dee5feea8384a000001), so I know we are operating on the same record. If I always follow the upsert with a find_by operation, I get the right id consistently, but it feels inefficient to have to run an upsert followed by a query.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm concerned that I will be getting the wrong id back in an operation where someone is, say, updating his profile repeatedly.

Comment: You didn't create the indexes: `rake db:mongoid:create_indexes`, otherwise the second attempt at a new document with the same email would have failed. If you keep creating new users, each will have a new `_id`. The `_id` is assigned immediately (and is visible in IRB). You just need to fetch it.

Comment: The last line in the User class creates the index. I checked it in MongoVue and the index is there. If I drop the collection and run the script again the index is recreated. To be safe though, I wanted to rule out the index portion, so with the index already in place, I commented out the last two lines of the User class, removed all records in the users collection and re-ran the script several times. It produces the same result... different ids each time it is run.

Comment: Just to clarify, running the above script against an empty collection (with the index in place) produces only 1 record, even if I run it 10 times in a row. So it seems like the index is holding true, and the _id in MongoDB itself stays consistent... it's only the _id that is returned in the mongoid document that keeps changing. I can do a fetch after each upsert using find_by, and that shows the right _id, but now I have to run two operations, insert and fetch, in order to get the _id.

Comment: No, the last line doesn't automatically create the index, per the docs (and my testing).

Comment: the id is here: `u.id`. It's available as soon as the document is created with `new`. Any attempt to create a second document with a duplicate email fails. I don't understand what you're trying to do. Every time you call `new` a new User is created, along with a new `_id`. The fact that there's an index on e-mail won't matter unless you try to save the document.

Comment: I checked that too and noticed that the id is created even before the doc is saved. Here is my potential use case:

Comment: 1) user logs in and creates his profile (unique by email address), 2) later the same function is used to update his profile (same record in MongoDB, because the same email address), but now I potentially have a different id in the User instance due to above problem 3) user creates an article, and I go to associate his user id with the article, but the user id isn't the same as what's stored in MongoDB because Mongoid returned a different id after the 2nd upsert. Only safe option is to run a record fetch for the user instead of using what's in session.

Comment: Grab the user id from session and put it in the `User` object. Depending on your situation, you may need to "load" the User before saving.